# How to avoid StackOverflowError NOT directly caused by recursion

Tags: java, stack-overflow, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Java application which reads Microsoft Word Documents (*.docx) and creates new stuff from their contents. It is in many ways a straightforward batch application. It works from a list of documents taken from a designated directory. It recurses all subfolders of this directory and creates a list of Strings which are the names of the docx documents. The list is then processed one at a time. It works correctly, processing all 288 documents in about 35 minutes and producing correct output for every document. In its single-threaded form it has been in use by me for three years without problems. In this case "correct" is what I define it to be, since it's my application.  I should say that I rarely run the entire 288 -- only when I add new features.

Many of the 288 documents are large -- 400 pages or more. Since my PC is a Core i7 which has 4 cores, each capable of two concurrent threads, I'd like to run some of these documents concurrently to see if it might be quicker.  I have tried using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to process the List, but I get a `StackOverflowError` about 20% of the way through the List.  Clearly the `StackOverflowError` is not caused by the subfolder recursion.

Is it simply a matter of making sure the objects created by each document go out of scope by themselves, or is there a recommended way of "forcing" them to release memory, such as setting to `null` at the end?  I have tried to do both of these partially without success, and it will take me a week to do either completely. Is there a better or recommended strategy?

The docx file format (what Microsoft calls Office Open XML) is a zip which contains XML files, which I convert using XSLT to my own format. That part is very straightforward -- using Java ZipFile and JAXP.

The application is written on the principle of a Library, ie with `Shelf` objects containing `Book` objects containing `Chapter` objects.  There are typically 10 to 20 chapters per book, each book is 300-500 pages or so, 288 books is the current count, over 100 more on the way.

All told the application is over 10,000 lines of code so not viable to post the code.  I deleted the few experimental lines of code for the `ExecutorService` -- it is a very simple API wrapping `Runnable`, and what I used was from googlable examples.  I will try to remake an example of what I did and post it.

Comment: Can you paste the code which is causing the Stack Overflow and indicate where it occurs?

Comment: Objects are created on heap. It should not cause StackOverflow error. Please, post some relevant code.

Comment: The normal max call depth is 1000, so there must be a genuine SO. Could there be a circular reference beyween documents (eg hyperlinks) or between components within a document?

Comment: have you tried to increase stack size? -Xss parameter of VM. Will it affect the  result?

Comment: Without a call stack it's hard to say what's going on. In java, all but native types (and arrays are not native types) are allocated on the heap, so the memory used by your objects is probably not an issue.

Comment: Each java thread has its own stack, so multiple threads should not cause a StackOverflowError in code that completes successfully in a single thread unless your threads are interacting in strange ways. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: How many threads are you spawning?  You tried fewer threads?  When you wrote "it works correctly", was it a single thread run going through all the documents?

Comment: When you said "it works correctly" (singlethreaded) did you let it finish all the documents?  Is it possible there's a malformed doc or transform causing infinite recursion in the XSLT processing?

Comment: A potentially very useful piece of information which you already have is still missing from your question: The stack trace of the StackOverflowError.

Comment: You mention "experimental lines of code for the `ExecutorService`"... did you create your own class implementing `ExecutorService`?

Comment: I apologize for not replying to these comments, but the hard drive on my dev machine failed and I am only just starting to get back to normal.  I think your comments may help me solve this. The main code structure consists of a List of Document objects. Each Document object contains a doubly linked list of Chapter objects each of which contains the text of a chapter.  I will keep you informed when I get back on schedule.